# Change time series frequency, ffill values until the next input but with a limit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have data with timestamps, I want to make it into 1min time series and fill the missing values in rows that are created with the last input. However, also have a limit on the ffill function as well. So, if the next input is missing for too long, leave NaN.

Data:

```
timestamp           pay
2020-10-10 23:32    50
2020-10-11 21:55    80
2020-10-13 23:28    40
```

Convert to this using `df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('1Min', method='ffill')`,
forward fill the pay column until the next input, **but if the next input is more than 24 hours away (1440 rows), only fill up to 1440 rows.**

So, `2020-10-11 21:55  80` should only filled with **80** until  `2020-10-12 21:55` , then leave NaN until `2020-10-13 23:28  40`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use **resample** and **ffill** with **limit** option. Can you try this:

```
mask = df.set_index('timestamp').sort_index().resample('1Min').ffill(limit=1440)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Clegane's very good answer I would like to add there is no need for `sort_index()` and the limit should be 1339 (1 value + 1339 makes the full day (1440)). Therefore:

```
output = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('1Min').fillna(method='ffill',limit=1339)
```

**Quality Check**

To ensure it's correctly working:

```
output['pay'].value_counts()
```

Returns:

```
50.0    1343 #Less than a day, so 100% filled
80.0    1440 #Over a day of range, so topped at 1440
40.0       1
Name: pay, dtype: int64
```